# Generate SQL Server Express database from Entity Framework 4 model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I am able to auto-generate a SQL Server CE 4.0 *.sdf file using code-first generation as explained by Scott Guthrie [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx). The connection string for the same is as follows:

```
<add name="NerdDinners" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
connectionString="data  source=|DataDirectory|NerdDinner.sdf"/>
```

However if I try to generate an mdf instead using the following connection string, it fails to do so with the following error - "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.".

```
<add name="NerdDinners" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data 
source=|DataDirectory|NerdDinner.mdf"/>
```

Even directly hooking into a SQLEXPRESS instance using the following connection string fails

```
<add name="NerdDinners" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data 
 Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NerdDinner;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Does EF 4 only support SQL CE 4.0 for database creation from a model for now or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Dunno; have you tried creating the database then using EF4 to create the schema?

Comment: Nice! ... Noone has a clue ...

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this connection string to work with SQL Express on the same tutorial.

```
<add name="NerdDinners" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=NerdDinners; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|NerdDinners.mdf; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note. If you're struggling to get the database to auto-create, it could well be because the database user you are using hasn't been given sufficient permissions. I was able to simply go the `Security` of the SQL **Instance** (not the database) and amend the `Securables` of the specific login so that it had the permission to `Create Any Database` (I didn't Grant any additional rights) and it allows EF4 to do its thing.